# vuex "store" vs "data: store" in Vue() constructor, which is best?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Vue docs mention to use "data" option on constructor, to keep global/shared data:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

This makes sense.

Vuex docs passes the "store" object, without a property name though:
https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/examples/counter/app.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(Counter)
})
```

Shouldn't that have been

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: store,
  render: h => h(Counter)
})
```

?

Other examples pass it as "store: store"
https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2017/04/25/vuejs-two-way-data-binding-state-management-vuex-strict-mode/

but "store" isn't a documented property:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/

Comment: `store` is a VueX thing: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getting-started.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `store` on your Vue instance is just shorthand for

`store: store`

https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand

Setting `store` on your main instance is part of Vuex and how Vuex interacts with your store so it is needed.

If you were to use your own global state setup without Vuex it would be perfectly fine to add your own store to the data. In fact a lot of application do this when there is no need for a full blown setup like Vuex yet.